# The parameter app_id is required Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, facebook-javascript-sdk, laravel-socialite

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('login/facebook', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/facebook/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

**Services.php**

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FB_KEY','188636635048329'),         // Your facbook Client ID
    'client_secret' => env('FB_SECRET','d16af66a2e168d05d87e76d618b48225'), // Your facbook Client Secret
    'redirect' => 'FB_CALLBACK','http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/callback',
],
```

**LoginController.php**

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    return $user->token;
}
```

I followed up with laravel Socialite Documentation but it didn't work it just showed **The parameter app_id is required** i trued to clear Config cache but it didn't work neither 
and i tried to put in .env file

```
FB_KEY = 188636635048329
FB_SECRET=d16af66a2e168d05d87e76d618b48225
FB_CALLBACK=http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/callback
```

but it didnt work so what else i can do to make it work

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/issues/620 is 188636635048329 a valid app at facebook?

Comment: yes i created a new app named it laravel to test it

Comment: do you miss env ? becomes : 'redirect' => env('FB_CALLBACK','http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/callback'),

Answer (score 0):

**solution**

The error was in the .env file i left some space in the FB_KEY so it should be like that

```
FB_KEY=188636635048329
```